# C++ MTL Library dimension.h bug?

Tags: c++, compilation, declaration

I've installed MTL on my Fedora Core 12 x64 system, but when building an application I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/mtl/matrix.h:41,
                 from /usr/local/include/mtl/mtl.h:40,
                 from ltiSystem.hxx:4,
                 from strTools.hxx:4,
                 from ff.cxx:3:
/usr/local/include/mtl/envelope2D.h:72: error: declaration of ‘typedef struct mtl::twod_tag mtl::envelope2D<T>::dimension’
/usr/local/include/mtl/dimension.h:19: error: changes meaning of ‘dimension’ from ‘class mtl::dimension<typename mtl::dense1D<T, 0>::size_type, 0, 0>’
make[1]: *** [ff.o] Error 1
```

Which would imply an error in MTL. I have changed to different MTL versions and the problem persists, but on Google there is no proper answer.
I use the g++ compiler.

Does anyone have a clye?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your code, almost hundred percent guarantee.

Look for ambiguous declaration with dimension, i.e.
`typedef mtl::envelope2D<T>::dimension dimension`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I thought so too, but it also happens with the test-suite that is bundled with MTL.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today with mtl-2.1.2-23.tentative.tar.gz version of MTL.

The solution was to change:

```
typedef dimension<size_type> dim_type;
```

to

```
typedef mtl::dimension<size_type> dim_type;
```

in the envelope2D.h file.
I also had to add

```
#include <cstddef>
```

at the begining of light1D.h.